# Do annotations apply to all variables in a declaration statement?

Tags: java, annotations

If multiple fields are declared in a single statement using a field annotation, does the annotation apply to all of the fields?

For example, will the following result in `x`, `y`, and `z` all having the `@Nullable` annotation?

```
@Nullable public Integer x, y, z;
```

I'm looking for an official specification on this, but have had trouble finding one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the closest we can get is this, [starting from §8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> ```
> FieldDeclaration:
>   {FieldModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList ;
>
> VariableDeclaratorList:
>   VariableDeclarator {, VariableDeclarator}
>
> VariableDeclarator:
>   VariableDeclaratorId [= VariableInitializer]
> ```

[And `FieldModifier` is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-FieldModifier):

> ```
> FieldModifier:
>   (one of)
>   Annotation public protected private
>   static final transient volatile
> ```

(So an annotation is a field modifier.)

And back to §8.3:

> More than one field may be declared in a single *FieldDeclaration* by using more than one declarator; **the *FieldModifier*s and *UnannType* apply to all the declarators in the declaration**.

So in otherwords, given:

```
@Nullable public Integer x, y, z;
```

We know that the field modifiers `@Nullable public` apply to all of `x`, `y` and `z`.

Also, reading a bit more of §8.3 as well as [§9.74](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4) will clarify that that's the case even if `@Nullable` is declared as a type annotation (i.e. `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`):

> It is possible for an annotation to appear at a syntactic location in a program where it could plausibly apply to a declaration, or a type, or both. This can happen in any of the five declaration contexts where modifiers immediately precede the type of the declared entity:
>
> - […]
> - Field declarations (including enum constants)
> - […]
>
> The grammar of the Java programming language unambiguously treats annotations at these locations as modifiers for a declaration (§8.3), […].

In other words, an annotation in such a location is always treated syntactically as a field modifier, *even if it's not considered a declaration annotation* (because it's not declared with `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)`). This is also hinted at in the grammar for field declarations, where the type is given as `UnannType`, i.e. *unannotated type*.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they all have the annotation.

The annotation is modifier of the type `Integer`, not for the `x`. So all the `x`, `y`, `z` are type `@Nullable Integer`